# I want to use a Angularjs Calendar where i can pass any language code like 'en-us' and it should change its text according to that language

Tags: angularjs

I have seen this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZrfDlSROZxKrOAiA0PXp?p=preview)  it is very nice but here we can not pass the language code.

```
<!doctype html>
```

```
Selected date is: {{dt | date:'fullDate' }}
```

```
<div class="well well-small pull-left" ng-model="dt">
  <datepicker min="minDate" show-weeks="showWeeks"></datepicker>
</div>

<div class="form-horizontal">
  <input type="text" datepicker-popup="dd-MMMM-yyyy" ng-model="dt" is-open="opened" min="minDate" max="'2015-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" />
  <button class="btn" ng-click="open()"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></button>
</div>

<hr />
<button class="btn btn-small btn-inverse" ng-click="today()">Today</button>
<button class="btn btn-small btn-inverse" ng-click="dt = '2009-08-24'">2009-08-24</button>
<button class="btn btn-small btn-success" ng-click="toggleWeeks()" tooltip="For inline datepicker">Toggle Weeks</button>
<button class="btn btn-small btn-danger" ng-click="clear()">Clear</button>
<button class="btn btn-small" ng-click="toggleMin()" tooltip="After today restriction">Min date</button>
```

Comment: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar/

Comment: is there any calendar which can take language code as parameter??? github example is nice but it is not fulfilling my requirement.

Comment: look at the source code and look at the library it's based on: http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.9.1/demos/languages.html